# Question about view controller controlability under alert view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the picture below, there is an alert view above the main view. When the alert view is shown, the buttons in the main view are not pressed. What should I do to be able to press the main view button while the alert view is showing?

If the main view's buttons can not be pressed while the alert view is showing, how can I press the main view's button to replace the alert view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alert view is controlled by a UIAlertViewController (note that UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS 8).  Per Apple's doc on UIAlertViewController:

```
UIKit displays alerts and action sheets modally over your app's content.
```

Since it's modal, there's no interactivity permitted with the view under the alert.  If you require such interactivity, you'd need to create a "fake" alert view by creating a hidden view (that's atop your other views) within your scene that looks like an alert.  Simply show the view and disable whatever buttons of your other views that you want to block interactivity.